# Checking if a list is empty with LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq, list

What's the "best" (taking both speed and readability into account) way to determine if a list is empty? Even if the list is of type `IEnumerable<T>` and doesn't have a Count property.

Right now I'm tossing up between this:

```
if (myList.Count() == 0) { ... }
```

and this:

```
if (!myList.Any()) { ... }
```

My guess is that the second option is faster, since it'll come back with a result as soon as it sees the first item, whereas the second option (for an IEnumerable) will need to visit every item to return the count.

That being said, does the second option look as readable to you? Which would you prefer? Or can you think of a better way to test for an empty list?

**Edit** @lassevk's response seems to be the most logical, coupled with a bit of runtime checking to use a cached count if possible, like this:

```
public static bool IsEmpty<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list)
{
    if (list is ICollection<T>) return ((ICollection<T>)list).Count == 0;

    return !list.Any();
}
```

Comment: Much more better don't mix `is` and `cast` but use `as` and `null` check: `ICollection<T> collection = list as ICollection<T>; if (collection != null) return colllection.Count;`

Comment: Why write an extra method? Isn't isn't `list.Any()` equivalent to `list.IsEmpty`? The framework method should be optimized -- it's worth writing a new one only if you figured out it's a perf bottleneck.

Comment: Did anyone bother to measure performance on their suggested implementations or is everyone just throwing out ideas?

Comment: I suggested issue to .NET Core class library that add `IsEmpty` extension method.

https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/35054

Please check and vote it if you like and agree.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

You could do this:

```
public static Boolean IsEmpty<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    if (source == null)
        return true; // or throw an exception
    return !source.Any();
}
```

**Edit**: Note that simply using the .Count method will be fast if the underlying source actually has a fast Count property. A valid optimization above would be to detect a few base types and simply use the .Count property of those, instead of the .Any() approach, but then fall back to .Any() if no guarantee can be made.

Comment: Or use one line and do return (source==null) ? true : !source.Any(); (If your not throwing an exception)

Comment: I would say, yes, throw an exception for null, but then add a second extension method called `IsNullOrEmpty()`.

Comment: public static Boolean IsNullOrEmpty<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
        {
            return source == null || !source.Any();
        }

Comment: @Gage Nowadays: `return !source?.Any() ?? true;`

Comment: @ricksmt Thanks for the update! I will definitely be using that!

Answer (score 14):

I would make one small addition to the code you seem to have settled on: check also for `ICollection`, as this is implemented even by some non-obsolete generic classes as well (i.e., `Queue<T>` and `Stack<T>`). I would also use `as` instead of `is` as it's more idiomatic and [has been shown to be faster](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/csharpcasts.aspx).

```
public static bool IsEmpty<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list)
{
    if (list == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("list");
    }

    var genericCollection = list as ICollection<T>;
    if (genericCollection != null)
    {
        return genericCollection.Count == 0;
    }

    var nonGenericCollection = list as ICollection;
    if (nonGenericCollection != null)
    {
        return nonGenericCollection.Count == 0;
    }

    return !list.Any();
}
```

Comment: I like this answer.  One word of warning is that some collections will throw exceptions when they don't fully implement an interface such as the `NotSupportedException` or `NotImplementedException`.  I first used your code example when I found out a collection I was using threw an exception for Count (who knew...).

Comment: I understand why such an optimization is useful for methods like Count() which needs to enumerate all elements. But Any() only needs to enumerate at most one element, so I fail to see the point here. On the other hand, the casts and the if-statements you are adding are a fixed cost you have to pay on every call then.

Answer (score 8):

> LINQ itself must be doing some serious optimization around the Count() method somehow.

Does this surprise you? I imagine that for `IList` implementations, `Count` simply reads the number of elements directly while `Any` has to query the `IEnumerable.GetEnumerator` method, create an instance and call `MoveNext` at least once.

/EDIT @Matt:

> I can only assume that the Count() extension method for IEnumerable is doing something like this:

Yes, of course it does. This is what I meant. Actually, it uses `ICollection` instead of `IList` but the result is the same.

Answer (score 7):

`List.Count` is O(1) according to Microsoft's documentation:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/27b47ht3.aspx

so just use `List.Count == 0` it's much faster than a query

This is because it has a data member called Count which is updated any time something is added or removed from the list, so when you call `List.Count` it doesn't have to iterate through every element to get it, it just returns the data member.

Comment: if it is a "IEnumerable" then no. (for starters IEnumerable doesn't have a "Count" property, it has a Count() method.).  Calling "Count()" will require the IEnumerable to examine every single element in the list. Whereas "Any" will just return as soon as it finds 1 element.

Comment: It depends on the data source. If you use yield to build an IEnumerable, it will have to traverse the IEnumerable to know it's size. So it is only O(1) in some cases. It is not always O(1).

Answer (score 6):

I just wrote up a quick test, try this:

```
 IEnumerable<Object> myList = new List<Object>();

 Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();

 int x;

 watch.Start();
 for (var i = 0; i <= 1000000; i++)
 {
    if (myList.Count() == 0) x = i; 
 }
 watch.Stop();

 Stopwatch watch2 = new Stopwatch();

 watch2.Start();
 for (var i = 0; i <= 1000000; i++)
 {
     if (!myList.Any()) x = i;
 }
 watch2.Stop();

 Console.WriteLine("myList.Count() = " + watch.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());
 Console.WriteLine("myList.Any() = " + watch2.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());
 Console.ReadLine();
```

The second is almost three times slower :)

Trying the stopwatch test again with a Stack or array or other scenarios it really depends on the type of list it seems - because they prove Count to be slower.

So I guess it depends on the type of list you're using!

(Just to point out, I put 2000+ objects in the List and count was still faster, opposite with other types)

Comment: `Enumerable.Count<T>()` has special handling for `ICollection<T>`. If you try this with something *other* than a basic list, I expect you'll see *significantly* different (slower) results. `Any()` will remain about the same, though.

Comment: I have to concur with Marc; this isn't a really fair test.

Comment: Any idea why there isn't special handling for `Enumerable.Any<T>()` for `ICollection<T>`? surely the parameterless `Any()` could just check the `Count` property for `ICollection<T>` too?

Answer (score 3):

The second option is much quicker if you have multiple items.

- `Any()` returns as soon as 1 item is found.
- `Count()` has to keep going through the entire list.

For instance suppose the enumeration had 1000 items.

- `Any()` would check the first one, then return true.
- `Count()` would return 1000 after traversing the entire enumeration.

This is potentially worse if you use one of the predicate overrides - Count() still has to check every single item, even it there is only one match.

You get used to using the Any one - it does make sense and is readable.

One caveat - if you have a List, rather than just an IEnumerable then use that list's Count property.

Comment: The differences between Any() and Count() seem clear, but @crucible's profiling code seems to indicate that Count() is faster for certain implementations of IEnumerable<T>. For List<T> I can't get Any() to give a faster result than Count() until the list size is up in the thousands of items. LINQ itself must be doing some serious optimization around the Count() method somehow.

Answer (score 3):

@Konrad what surprises me is that in my tests, I'm passing the list into a method that accepts `IEnumerable<T>`, so the runtime can't optimize it by calling the Count() extension method for `IList<T>`.

I can only assume that the Count() extension method for IEnumerable is doing something like this:

```
public static int Count<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list)
{
    if (list is IList<T>) return ((IList<T>)list).Count;

    int i = 0;
    foreach (var t in list) i++;
    return i;
}
```

... in other words, a bit of runtime optimization for the special case of `IList<T>`.

/EDIT @Konrad +1 mate - you're right about it more likely being on `ICollection<T>`.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so what about this one?

```
public static bool IsEmpty<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
{
    return !enumerable.GetEnumerator().MoveNext();
}
```

EDIT: I've just realized that someone has sketched this solution already. It was mentioned that the Any() method will do this, but why not do it yourself? Regards

Comment: BUT it becomes less succinct when you properly enclose it in a `using` block since otherwise you've constructed an `IDisposable` object and then abandoned it. Then, of course, it become *more* succinct when you utilize the extension method that's already there and just change it to `return !enumerable.Any()` (which does precisely this).

Comment: Why rewriting an already existing method ? As mentioned `Any()` performs exactly that, so adding exactly the same method with another name will just be confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Another idea:

```
if(enumerable.FirstOrDefault() != null)
```

However I like the Any() approach more.

Comment: What if you have a non-empty list in which the first element is null?

Answer (score 0):

If I check with Count() Linq executes a "SELECT COUNT(*).." in the database, but I need to check if the results contains data, I resolved to introducing FirstOrDefault() instead of Count();

Before

```
var cfop = from tabelaCFOPs in ERPDAOManager.GetTable<TabelaCFOPs>()

if (cfop.Count() > 0)
{
    var itemCfop = cfop.First();
    //....
}
```

After

```
var cfop = from tabelaCFOPs in ERPDAOManager.GetTable<TabelaCFOPs>()

var itemCfop = cfop.FirstOrDefault();

if (itemCfop != null)
{
    //....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This was critical to get this to work with Entity Framework:

```
var genericCollection = list as ICollection<T>;

if (genericCollection != null)
{
   //your code 
}
```

Comment: How does that answer the question ? the collection can be not null while having no elements inside it.

Answer (score 0):

```
private bool NullTest<T>(T[] list, string attribute)

    {
        bool status = false;
        if (list != null)
        {
            int flag = 0;
            var property = GetProperty(list.FirstOrDefault(), attribute);
            foreach (T obj in list)
            {
                if (property.GetValue(obj, null) == null)
                    flag++;
            }
            status = flag == 0 ? true : false;
        }
        return status;
    }


public PropertyInfo GetProperty<T>(T obj, string str)

    {
        Expression<Func<T, string, PropertyInfo>> GetProperty = (TypeObj, Column) => TypeObj.GetType().GetProperty(TypeObj
            .GetType().GetProperties().ToList()
            .Find(property => property.Name
            .ToLower() == Column
            .ToLower()).Name.ToString());
        return GetProperty.Compile()(obj, str);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my implementation of Dan Tao's answer, allowing for a predicate:

```
public static bool IsEmpty<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate)
{
    if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException();
    if (IsCollectionAndEmpty(source)) return true;
    return !source.Any(predicate);
}

public static bool IsEmpty<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source)
{
    if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException();
    if (IsCollectionAndEmpty(source)) return true;
    return !source.Any();
}

private static bool IsCollectionAndEmpty<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource> source)
{
    var genericCollection = source as ICollection<TSource>;
    if (genericCollection != null) return genericCollection.Count == 0;
    var nonGenericCollection = source as ICollection;
    if (nonGenericCollection != null) return nonGenericCollection.Count == 0;
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
List<T> li = new List<T>();
(li.First().DefaultValue.HasValue) ? string.Format("{0:yyyy/MM/dd}", sender.First().DefaultValue.Value) : string.Empty;
```

Answer (score -4):

`myList.ToList().Count == 0`. That's all

Comment: This is an awful idea. ToList() should not be overused, as it forces the enumerable to be fully evaluated. Use .Any() instead.

Answer (score -6):

This extension method works for me:

```
public static bool IsEmpty<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
{
    try
    {
        enumerable.First();
        return false;
    }
    catch (InvalidOperationException)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Avoid such use of exceptions. In the above code, you *expect* an exception for certain, well-defined inputs (i.e. empty enumerations). Hence, they are no exceptions, they are the rule. That’s an abuse of this control mechanism which has implications on readability and performance. Reserve the use of exceptions for truly exceptional cases.

Comment: Generally, I would agree. But this is a workaround for a corresponding missing IsEmpty method. And I would argue that a workaround never is the ideal way to do something... Furthermore, especially in this case, the intent is very clear and the "dirty" code is encapsulated and hidden away in a well-defined place.

Comment: -1: If you want to do it this way, use FirstOrDefault(), as in ChulioMartinez's answer.

Comment: Exception handling has really poor performance efficiency.
So this may be the worst solution here.

Comment: "Exceptions should be exceptional." - do not use them for normal program flow.