# Is there a more elegant way to find out if a list has elements than to use count?

Tags: c#, list

At the moment I use the following procedure to determine if a list has elements:

```
if (aList.Count > 0)
{
   //doStuff
}
```

I'm asking myself if there is a more elegant way to find out if there are elements, without using a comparison.

Comment: Why don't you consider that an elegant solution?

Comment: Well looking at it again, this is a really good question. I think I am just a blockhead from looking at code all day.

Comment: Both solutions are good. I think Any() is slightly more readable.

Comment: @ChrisKooken - Don't forget that `Any()` means you have to reference `LINQ`... not always possible or optimal.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Count` is the best option - it is a property of `List<>` meaning that access time is `O(1)`.

It is also descriptive.

Comment: To be precise, `Any()` is exactly the same in this respect. It checks if the IEnumerable is IList and if it is, it returns Count != 0.

Comment: @Shedal - For `IList`, yes, albeit with the extra step to check for type.

Comment: You're right. I think I was just looking for a property like list.hasItems which clearly doesn't exist.

Answer (score 8):

You can use linq:

```
if (aList.Any())
{
   //doStuff
}
```

Comment: Good to know! Thank you. But I think I'll stick with count > 0 because it's not calling another function.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose if it's the wording that bothers you and you want a more expressive way to describe it, you could write a custom extension method:

```
public static bool HasItems(this IList<T> list)
{
    return list.Count > 0;
}
```

Then you'd use it like this:

```
if (aList.HasItems())
{
   //doStuff
}
```

It's a matter of personal preference, really.  The term `HasItems` may, for example, sound more intuitive than `Count > 0` and may even look a little cleaner (again, subjectively).

However, what I personally don't like about it is that it's a method rather than a property.  (I personally would *love* if C# added support for "extension properties.")  There are exceptions, but to me intuitively I expect a property to just give me information on the state of something (hopefully in `O(1)` time [as Oded mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10107775/328193)), whereas I would expect a method to "do something" and have some sort of side-effect on the state of the object.

Again, it's all a matter of personal preference.  Just an option that's available to you.

Answer (score 1):

you can write extension method as below

```
    public static Boolean IsEmpty<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sourceList)
    {
       return (sourceList==null) ? true : !sourceList.Any();
    }
```

see this question for more info - [Checking if a list is empty with LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41319/checking-if-a-list-is-empty-with-linq)

Answer (score 0):

This is already a most elegant solution.

Can use (just an example) `Count(x=>x..condition..);` linq type to find out the count of the elements sutisfying some specified condition.

Answer (score 0):

I wrapped this check in an extension (Null checking AND checking for items is cumbersome imo)

```
  public static bool IsAny<T>(this IEnumerable<T> item)
  {
            return item != null && item.Any();
  }

// Usage
listOfFoo.IsAny()
```