# Is there an equivalent of "None()" in LINQ?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I've been running into situations where I feel I'm lacking a LINQ extension method which effectivelly checks if there is no match of the specified predicate in a collection. There is `Any` and `All`, but if I for instance use the following code:

`if (Objects.All(u => u.Distance <= 0))`

This returns true if all the objects in the collection are 0 or less yards away.

`if (Objects.Any(u => u.Distance <= 0))`

This returns true if there is at least one object in the collection which is 0 or less yards away from me.

So far so good, both those methods make sense and the syntax for them makes sense too. Now, if I want to check if there is no object with 0 or less distance, I'd have to invert the predicate inside the `All` method to `>= 0` instead of `<= 0` or call `!All()`, which in some cases results in very poorly readable code.

Is there no method which effectively does `Collection.None(u => u.Distance <= 0)` to check if there is no object in the collection which is 0 or less yards away? It's syntactic sugar more than an actual problem, but I just have the feeling it's missing.

Comment: Extension methods are you friend here. If you need Collection.None, define one...

Comment: @DavidArno There is already a method which effectively does what the question asks (`Any`). The OP doesn't like it, not because it doesn't do what the OP's looking for, but because it doesn't look pretty. What's pretty and what isn't is largely opinion based. I didn't vote, nor am I going to, but I can see why someone else might.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Checking if a list is empty with LINQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41319/checking-if-a-list-is-empty-with-linq)

Comment: I'm not asking how to check if a collection is empty, I'm asking if there's a method which returns true if *none* of the values in the list match the predicate. And I'm not saying I don't like `Any`, I love `Any`. I'm asking if there's a method in existence in LINQ which I feel is missing: `None`.

Comment: No, it isn't a duplicate as "Checking if a list is empty with LINQ" is concerned with checking if a list is empty, whereas this question is concerned with handling situations where no elements of a non-empty list match some critia.

Comment: @aevitas how does `None(somCondition)` differ from `!Any(someCondition)` or `All(!someCondition)`? SQL doesn't have such an operator either, for the same reason. In fact, how would you define `None`? Wouldn't it be `when there isn't Any item that matches someCondition` ?

Comment: @aevitas besides, there is no logic symbol in [predicate logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existential_quantification) either. It's either `NOT ANY 0 ¬∃` or `ALL NOT - ∀ ... ¬P(x)`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos That's probably the reason the designers of LINQ didn't include a method for it, makes sense now. Thanks for the link! :)

Comment: I also think that defining none is more readable than having "!" in front of Any(). At the same time others think otherwise.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

`None` is the same as `!Any`, so you could define your own extension method as follows:

```
public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static bool None<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
                                     Func<TSource, bool> predicate)
    {
        return !source.Any(predicate);
    }
}
```

Comment: None is the same as `!All` too, that's why it's so weird that there's no `None`. I guess I'll stick to writing my own extension as you suggested and hope they'll add it at a later point.

Comment: No `!Any`. `!All` will succeed from the moment one item doesn't pass the test. None means there is no element that passes the test. `!All` could be explained as `AnyNot`. In logic, `exist neg x` is not equal to `neg exists x`

Comment: @aevitas `None` is not the same as `!All`, although one could create a `NotAll` extension method. But why not `HardlyAny` or `AFew` ;)

Comment: @aevitas: As you said, using `All` you have to invert the predicate. Sometimes you need `None`; that's where I use `!Any`.

Comment: @dtb `None` may be helpful as a shorthand but isn't needed. There is no `None` symbol in [predicate logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existential_quantification). It's either `NOT ANY` or `ALL NOT`

Comment: If one was going to do this then unless *really* sure it wouldn't come up, it would good to have `public static bool None<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> predicate) => !source.Any(predicate);`. Otherwise if called on an `IQueryable<T>` with a lamdba it would end up calling the method you have, and forcing it to be performed as an enumerable.

Comment: This is very useful to stop ReSharper from changing all your `!Any(a => a == x)` to `All(a => a != x)`.

Answer (score 6):

You can write your own `Extension Method`:

```
public static bool None(this IEnumerable<T> collection, Func<T, bool> predicate)
{
  return collection.All(p=>predicate(p)==false);
}
```

Or on `IQueryable<T>` as well

```
public static bool None(this IQueryable<T> collection, Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> predicate)
{
  return collection.All(p=> predicate(p)==false);
}
```

Comment: using `p=>!Predicate(p)` is more succinct.

Comment: @KingKing But less readable, although it is my personal idea.

Comment: @Alireza sure, it's just your feeling, I don't feel so.

Comment: @KingKing Yes.I said it is my own personal feeling nothing general. But sometimes '!' hides itself behind characters :)

Comment: `== false` is less readable, because it's unusual. Also, you can't do `predicate(p)` in the second case, though you could return `!collection.Any(predicate)` which would also have the benefit in the first example of not creating a new delegate.

Answer (score 1):

Even shorter version

```
static class LinqExtensions
{
    public static bool None<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate) => !source.Any(predicate);
}
```