# Is there an equivalent of "Array.None" in JS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

There's a similar question for LINQ: [Is there an equivalent of `None()` in LINQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19338122/1366033)

There are some boolean methods on collections / arrays:

- [`Array.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) (similar to [`linq.Any`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=netcore-3.1))
- [`Array.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) (similar to [`linq.All`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.all?view=netcore-3.1))

Can I check if no elements in array match a given function callback

A possible workaround is to `.filter` and then check `.length` and make sure it's zero:

```js
let arr = ["a","b","c"]
// make sure that no item in array = "b"
let noBs = arr.filter(el => el === "b").length === 0
```

Answer (score 65, accepted):

As logically concluded by the linq example

> `None` is the same as `!Any`, so you could define your own extension method as follows:

```js
let none = (arr, callback) => !arr.some(callback)
```

And then call like this:

```js
let arr = ["a","b","c"]
let noBs = none(arr, el => el === "b")
```

---

*Or* if you want to [*extend `Array.proto`*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35518127/1366033), you can add the following method:

```js
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'none', {
    value: function (callback) { return !this.some(callback) }
});
```

Then call like this:

```js
let arr = ["a","b","c"]
let noBs = arr.none(el => el === "b")
```

Answer (score 10):

Not at the moment

At the moment I'm using an `Array.some()` and then negating the whole thing

Personally I think an Array.none function would be awesome

You could [request](https://github.com/tc39/ecma262/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md) it to be added to the next release of ECMA. It looks like a bit of a process to say the least but if we wanted to get this added to ECMA this would be the way.

Comment: **Warning:** `not every` is not the same as `none`!

Comment: oh yes I think i meant ! Array.any Thanks for pointing that out, will update my answer

Comment: I think you mean `Array.some` (to my knowledge there's no `any` alias in JS).

Comment: `!Array.some(...)` will be true when every entry is falsy, and false otherwise

Answer (score 2):

Liked the @KyledMit approach. On the similar lines, using the `findIndex` is another way. (`find` may not be reliable as we can not check on return value).

```js
const arr = ["a","b","c"]

const noBs = arr.findIndex(el => el === "b") < 0;

console.log(noBs)
```

Answer (score -1):

If it's an array with scalar values, you can use `Array.prototype.includes()`

```js
const arr = ["a", "b", "c"]
const includesB = arr.includes("b")
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes