# Shortcut for vb null and Any() checks

Tags: vb.net, linq

I'm sorry if asked before...if so, I did not find it.

I was reading [A Shortcut for c# null and Any() checks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28903952/a-shortcut-for-c-sharp-null-and-any-checks) and I saw the accepted answer. I understand the answer, although most people use x.Items?.Any() ?? false.

My question is: How to do this is VB.NET

Could I just simply write

```
If x.Items?.Any() Then
```

or do I need

```
If x.Items?.Any() = True Then
```

While if (x.Items?.Any()) does not compile in C#, they both do in VB...but that doesn't always mean they are both correct :-)

Comment: If Items is nullable, so Any() will return bool?. So it should be = True to avoid null.

Comment: As far as I get it, this compiles because VB autocasts bool? to bool. If the values is really null at runtime, this will crash obviously.
But will this ever be null?

Comment: Actually, both of them won't crash in the if case. Because there is exact type comparision. If items is null, either true or false will not equal to null.

Comment: I can't even test on .NET Fiddle :s https://dotnetfiddle.net/5K5GE5

Comment: Select compiler Roslyn 3.8

Comment: The VB equivalent to C# `??` is the two-argument operator form of `If`.  That is, `x ?? y` in C# is the same as `If(x, y)` in VB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some tests on .NET Fiddle I found out both work

```
Imports System
Imports System.Linq
            
Public Module Module1
  public Class Vehicle

  End Class

  Public Sub Main()

    Dim x as System.Collections.Generic.List(Of Vehicle)
    
    Dim y as System.Collections.Generic.List(Of Vehicle)
    y = new System.Collections.Generic.List(of Vehicle)
    
    Dim z as System.Collections.Generic.List(Of Vehicle)
    z = new System.Collections.Generic.List(of Vehicle)
    
    z.Add(new Vehicle())
        
    If (x?.Any() = True) Then
        Console.WriteLine("X YES")
    Else
        Console.WriteLine("X NO")
    End If
    
    If (x?.Any()) Then
        Console.WriteLine("X YES")
    Else
        Console.WriteLine("X NO")
    End If
    
    If (y?.Any() = True) Then
        Console.WriteLine("Y YES")
    Else
        Console.WriteLine("Y NO")
    End If
    
    If (y?.Any()) Then
        Console.WriteLine("Y YES")
    Else
        Console.WriteLine("Y NO")
    End If
    
    If (z?.Any() = True) Then
        Console.WriteLine("Z YES")
    Else
        Console.WriteLine("Z NO")
    End If
    
    If (z?.Any()) Then
        Console.WriteLine("Z YES")
    Else
        Console.WriteLine("Z NO")
    End If
End Sub
End Module
```

will result in

```
X NO
X NO
Y NO
Y NO
Z YES
Z YES
```

as excpected

Comment: What happens if you remove the parentheses?

Answer (score 1):

When I tested the following on LinqPad:

```vb
Dim lst As List(Of Vehicle) = Nothing
If lst?.Any Then
    Console.WriteLine("True")
Else
    Console.WriteLine("False")
End If
```

it works just fine, and prints `False`, even with `Option Strict On`.

It also works from within Visual Studio in a .NET 5 console app.

It would seem that Visual Basic supports using `Boolean?` in the test of an `If` statement.

And it now seems to work [on .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/aq1qFg).

Comment: Your code will resolve to `False` because the `?` shortcut resolves to null/Nothing and the `Any()` is not even tested. If `lst` was not null but empty (ie `= New List(Of Vehicle)`), it would resolve to `False` due to the `Any()` test.

Comment: @SteveCinq I'm not quite sure what you're trying to say. Isn't that the point? Whether the list is `Nothing`, or the list is empty, the "else" branch of the `If` will be executed.

Comment: Just highlighting the "why" side. Not a criticism.